# Are different :focus styles possible depending on if user clicks an element or tabs to it?

Tags: css, focus

I'm currently styling a webpage for user interaction based on tabbing through the page.

**Is there a way to style an element one way if the user focuses that element by clicking the mouse, and another way if they tab to it?**

I would like to have different styles because I want the elements that get tabbed to bolder than the ones they click on. Trying to make it easier to see where they are on the page.

I know how to accomplish this with javascript, just wondering if anyone has a CSS solution up their sleeve.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can, since the CSS code isn't aware of the way you focused an element, but just know that it has focus in that moment. I guess you have to use a javascript code to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pseudo-classes like this:

```
a:hover { color: green; } /* hover */
a:active { color: blue; } /* click and hold */
a:focus { color: red; } /* tab to it */
```

Comment: `:active` is not the same as triggering `:focus` with a mouse click. Even if you declare `:active` and `:focus`, `:focus` can still take effect directly after you release the mouse button.